# Linux/Cygwin: Replace Pattern with Result of Other Pattern Match (sed/find?)

Tags: replace, sed, find, cygwin, extract

I have a large website of documents that look like this:
`<title>DOCTITLE</title>`
`<h1>Some Title</h1>`

I'm trying to use Cygwin to replace DOCTITLE with Some Title in every file.

To be more specific, I need to extract whatever text is between `<h1>` tags from each file and replace the literal string "DOCTITLE" with the extracted text.

Here's one thought that doesn't work but illustrates the spirit of what I'm after:

```
find . -name "*html"  
       -exec sed -i 
                's/DOCTITLE/'$(grep "h1" | sed 's/<h1>\(.*\)<\/h1>/\1/')'/'
'{}' /;
```

Unsurprisingly, this fails because grep has no input and it would destroy the `<h1>`.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your time and expertise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach—using `$( … )`—won't work, since `sed`'s `-exec` argument doesn't handle that syntax.  What we can do instead, however, is call `bash` to do that bit of work for us:

```
find . -name '*.html' -exec /bin/bash -c 'sed "s/DOCTITLE/$(sed -n '\''\,<h1>.*</h1>,{s,<h1>\(.*\)</h1>,\1,p;q}'\'' '\''{}'\'')/" "{}"' \;
```

The outer `sed` does exactly what your `sed` command does. The inner `$( … )` part is expanded by `bash` to produce only the text between the *first* `<h1>`s (it'd be much simpler if it didn't need to only get that first match).

Specifically, that inner `sed` prints nothing by default (the `-n`), then for lines that match the regex `<h1>.*</h1>`, it runs `s,<h1>\(.*\)</h1>,\1,p;q`, ie strip the HTML tags, print the result, then quit; that `q` ensures we only print out the first match.

Note I've avoided needing to use `grep` by using `sed -n`; you could alteratively do the same thing with the below command, with the `-m` option to `grep` limiting the command to the first match.

```
find . -name '*.html' -exec /bin/bash -c 'sed "s/DOCTITLE/$(grep -m1 '\''<h1>.*</h1>'\'' '\''{}'\'' | sed '\''s,<h1>\(.*\)</h1>,\1,'\'')/" "{}"' \;
```

In both cases, there's some mildly horrific quoting going on: the `'\''` sequences are to insert a single quote into a single-quoted string. We need to quote the `sed` statements to ensure any spaces in the titles don't cause problems, and we need to quote the file names to be able to handle spaces in file names.

Comment: That did it! Thanks a ton. Nice job finding just the first `<h1>` and avoiding further "slash-itis" by using the comma as a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
find . -name "*html" -exec sed -i '$!N;s/DOCTITLE\([^\n]*\n<h1>\([^<]*\)<\/h1>\)/\2\1/;P;D' {}\;
```

This will need extensive testing first!